# Simplifying a matrix expression with a MatrixSymbol in Python

Tags: python, sympy

I am using SymPy for symbolic matrix calculations, however, certain statements are very big. It seems there is a way to simplify them further. I have used `simplify()` but I have not been successful in getting what I want.

For example the image below is a matrix, which has been obtained as result of execution of long list of previous matrix calculations. 
[The output of series of matrix calculations, which requires further simplification](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rDQUq.png)

The final statement has two additions and one matrix multiplication. I wonder if there is any way to also execute the matrix multiplication on the right so we can simply end up with 3 matrix summations?

I understand this can be done by doing certain algebraic manipulations by hand but I am more interested in a command to execute, such that the command takes the whole statement as the input and does all the simplifications including any multiplications and additions and outputs what I need. This should all be done using `sympy`. In other words, if an addition or a multiplication can be done then I want it done and not being left undone.

This is MCVE, which mimics my problem

```
from sympy import *
init_printing()
J_22 = MatrixSymbol('J_22', 3, 3)
COV_b=Matrix([[2,1,1],[1,2,1],[1,1,2]])
(COV_b+J_22)*COV_b
```

The output of this code is

[image: The output of the MCVE]

However, I would like to have this as the output

[image: The desired output]

I understand that in this simple example I could simply fix the problem by the following code

```
from sympy import *
init_printing()
J_22 = MatrixSymbol('J_22', 3, 3)
COV_b=Matrix([[2,1,1],[1,2,1],[1,1,2]])
(COV_b*COV_b+J_22*COV_b)
```

However, this is just a simple example, in the actual problem this cannot be seen before the output is generated. Hence, I would like to be able to use a command, which takes the output of the first provided code as input and outputs the desired output.

UPDATE:@WelcometoStackOverflow provided a function, which simplifies things a lot but still leaves the matrix addition undone.

```
from sympy import *
init_printing()
J_22 = MatrixSymbol('J_22', 3, 3)
COV_b=Matrix([[2,1,1],[1,2,1],[1,1,2]])
T=(COV_b+J_22)*COV_b+COV_b
def expand_matmul(expr):
    import itertools
    for a in preorder_traversal(expr):
        if isinstance(a, MatMul):
            terms = [f.args if isinstance(f, MatAdd) else [f] for f in a.args]
            expanded = Add(*[MatMul(*t) for t in itertools.product(*terms)])
            if a != expanded:
                expr = expr.xreplace({a: expanded})
                return expand_matmul(expr)
    return expr
expand_matmul(T)
```

The output is

[image: enter image description here[4]]

with the summation between the first two matrices still not executed.

Comment: @WelcometoStackOverflow Thanks for this. Yes, I understand, I will try to edit this. Unfortunately, the actual code is very long. I try to do a code to mimic my problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a known and old issue with SymPy expressions: [Can't expand matrix expression](https://github.com/sympy/sympy/issues/10360). Matrix Expressions module is useful, but is not the most actively maintained in SymPy. I put together a function to expand such things.

```
def expand_matmul(expr):
    import itertools
    for a in preorder_traversal(expr):
        if isinstance(a, MatMul) and any(isinstance(f, MatAdd) for f in a.args):
            terms = [f.args if isinstance(f, MatAdd) else [f] for f in a.args]
            expanded = MatAdd(*[MatMul(*t) for t in itertools.product(*terms)])
            if a != expanded:
                expr = expr.xreplace({a: expanded})
                return expand_matmul(expr)
    return expr
```

The function walks the expression tree from the highest levels, looking for an opportunity to expand MatMul. The returned expression may benefit from `doit` method invocation to perform any undone multiplication from explicit matrices, as in the example below.

```
J_22 = MatrixSymbol('J_22', 3, 3)
COV_b=Matrix([[2,1,1],[1,2,1],[1,1,2]])
T=(COV_b+J_22)*COV_b+COV_b  
pprint(expand_matmul(T).doit())
```

prints

```
⎡8  6  6⎤       ⎡2  1  1⎤
⎢       ⎥       ⎢       ⎥
⎢6  8  6⎥ + J₂₂⋅⎢1  2  1⎥
⎢       ⎥       ⎢       ⎥
⎣6  6  8⎦       ⎣1  1  2⎦
```

Comment: Thanks for taking time to code the function. It works perfectly! However, still leaves the matrix addition undone! I will update the question to reflect this. I do not think I can add chunks of code in the comments.

Comment: A small piece of code, like `(COV_b+J_22)*COV_b+COV_b `, is fine in a comment (between backticks). I slightly updated the function so it now handles this expression too.